# postDelayed execute twice for running code

Tags: android

I've seen a video tutorial and in that tutorial the tutor write some codes like this :

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_plus){

        isPlusButtonPressed = true;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isPlusButtonPressed){
                    incrementValue();
                    handler.postDelayed(this,100);
                }
            }
        },0);
    }else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_minus){
        isMinusButtonPressed = true;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isMinusButtonPressed){
                    decrementValue();
                    handler.postDelayed(this,100);
                }
            }
        }, 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can't understand why 'handler.postDelayed' was wrote twice in each of the onLongClick method if statements . If I erase that line of code then the code will not work correctly

Comment: the first one is if longpress is on hte plus button, the second one is if the longpress is on the minus button. first one calls incrementValye() and second one calls decrementValue().

Comment: @JoachimHaglund No my point is two postDelayed in each of 'if' statement . first one is in the body of if statement and the second one is into the first one 'handler.postDelayed(this,100);'

Comment: what does the increment and decrement methods do, and what is the point of the booleans isPlusButtonPressed and isMinusButtonPressed?

Comment: it is not on-topic to ask us to explain code. You should ask the one who wrote it.

Comment: @JoachimHaglund I built a custom view that has two button . One for increase a value and the other one for decrease it .I want to change the value continuously when I holding the buttons . increment and decrement methods used for this job and isPlusButtonPressed and the other one set true when user hold the button and set false when user release it (in the touch event method )

Comment: oh okay, well then the second call is just to make sure that it keeps increasing. After calling incrementValue() it calls postdelayed with itself and 100 milliseconds delay as arguments, so it becomes a recursive method that calls itself with a delay everytime it finishes.